# Is it possible to reinstall S Notes after flashing Lineage OS 14.1 on Samsung Galaxy Note 8?

Tags: lineageos, s-note

I'm a beginner with rooting, flashing and so on, but I'd like to try to flash Lineage OS 14.1 on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8 (GT-N5100). However I often use S Note for taking notes using the S Pen. Does anybody know if it is possible to somehow get and reinstall the S Note App after flashing the new OS? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S Note is tightly integrated with Samsung's framework and thus can't be ported to non-stock-based ROMs.

In the meantime, try [Squid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steadfastinnovation.android.projectpapyrus) as an alternative. Lots of available pre-defined notes, export to PDF, and best of all it makes use of the spare button on the pen that LineageOS doesn't use.

Comment: Squid works well for me too. No issues on my Note8 N5100 tablet.

Comment: Just created an subaccount here to say that this is actually nicer than the stock... Nice suggestion. Loved it :) - And it even has official support for the S Pen, letting you choose what to do when pressing the button, etc